# java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state On weblogic 9

Tags: jdbc

We are getting this error "java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state " when executing our web app on weblogic 9. The jdk used is 1.5 and database is Oracle10.2g
We have switched out oracle drivers ojdbc14.jar with ojdbc5.jar. We have also added orai18n.jar. We have ensured that this change of jar occurs with the web app library as well as other weblogic server classpaths where ojdbc14.jar existed.

The problem persists

Any pointers would help

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade your jdbc driver to version 11.2

please check the link below:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_24893929.html